# OIDC callback "Bad authentication response, error=access_denied"

Tags: spring-boot, pac4j

We have a spring-boot with pac4j application that integrates with Orcid using CAS credentials.
We have multi profile configuration with two OidcClients - CAS and a basic OidcClient for ORCID.
Issue:
Is there a way to configure Oidc callback similarly to the Oauth examples?
OathConfiguration has the setHasBeenCancelledFactory when user Denies auth and I am trying to find out how to implement that with the OIDC Client/Configuration.

PAC4JConfig.java
...

```
public Config config() {
    final OidcConfiguration oidcConfiguration = new OidcConfiguration();
    oidcConfiguration.setClientId(orcidClientId);
    oidcConfiguration.setSecret(orcidClientSecret);
    oidcConfiguration.setUseNonce(true);
    oidcConfiguration.setDiscoveryURI(orcidDiscoveryUrl);
    oidcConfiguration.setScope(orcidClientScope);
             oidcConfiguration.setClientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_POST);

    final OidcClient oidcClient = new OidcClient(oidcConfiguration);
    oidcClient.setName(Constants.ORCID_CLIENT_NAME);
    oidcClient.setCallbackUrl(callbackUrl);
    oidcClient.setSaveProfileInSession(true);
    oidcClient.setMultiProfile(true);
    final CasConfiguration configuration = new CasConfiguration(casLoginUrl);
    final CasClient casClient = new CasClient(configuration);
    casClient.setName(Constants.CAS_CLIENT_NAME);
    casClient.setMultiProfile(true);
    final Clients clients = new Clients(callbackUrl, oidcClient, casClient);
    return new Config(clients);
}
```

OrcidConnectController.java

```
    @RequestMapping("/orcid/forceLogin")
    @ResponseBody
    public void forceLogin() {
        try {
            final String name = webContext.getRequestParameter(Pac4jConstants.DEFAULT_CLIENT_NAME_PARAMETER)
                    .map(String::valueOf).orElse(""); 
            final Client client = config.getClients().findClient(name).get();
            JEESessionStore.INSTANCE.set(webContext, Pac4jConstants.REQUESTED_URL, "/orcid/connect");
            JEEHttpActionAdapter.INSTANCE.adapt(client.getRedirectionAction(new CallContext(webContext, JEESessionStore.INSTANCE)).get(), webContext);
        } catch (final HttpAction e) {
            log.error("Forcelogin error :{}", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the `HasBeenCancelledFactory` concept is only available for OAuth and not for OIDC.

That said, the error message you get is from the `OidcExtractor`:

```java
if (response instanceof AuthenticationErrorResponse) {
    logger.error("Bad authentication response, error={}",
                    ((AuthenticationErrorResponse) response).getErrorObject());
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

which returns an empty credential like for OAuth with the `HasBeenCancelledFactory`:

```java
final boolean hasBeenCancelled = (Boolean) configuration.getHasBeenCancelledFactory().apply(context);
// check if the authentication has been cancelled
if (hasBeenCancelled) {
    logger.debug("authentication has been cancelled by user");
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

I think what you need here is to set a profile (maybe the `AnonymousProfile`) when you are not authenticated via the `profileFactoryWhenNotAuthenticated` of your Orcid OIDC client.

See: https://www.pac4j.org/5.7.x/docs/clients.html#8-silent-login